# Calculating a Deflection of Light Integral from Einstein's 1907 paper on Gravity and Light

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, refraction

$\frac{1}{c^2}\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=\pi/2} \frac{kM}{r^2}cos\theta ds=2\frac{kM}{c^2\Delta}$

An observation:  $\cos\theta=\frac{\Delta}{r}$

[image]

Comment: The entire calculation is done in an early section of the answere here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14056/

Comment: Thanks! I've read quite a bit of the other sections as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

$s = \Delta \tan\theta \quad \Rightarrow \quad  ds = \frac{\Delta}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta $

and

$r = \frac{\Delta }{\cos \theta }$

and insert it into your integral. What you get is

$\frac{1}{c^2} \intop_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{kM}{\Delta } \cos\theta  d\theta = 2 \frac{kM}{c^2 \Delta} $.