# Was Einstein's Cross Predicted by Einstein's Theories?

Tags: gravity, visible-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does gravitational lensing account for Einstein’s Cross?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/how-does-gravitational-lensing-account-for-einsteins-cross)

[Einstein's Cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_Cross) is a fascinating phenomena for which I have asked [explanation here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/how-does-gravitational-lensing-account-for-einsteins-cross/14063). However, I'm also interested to know if Einstein's cross was a specific prediction that people had obtained from Einstein's theories such as General Relativity or if the phenomena was merely named after Einstein. The wiki page on [Einstein's Ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_ring) explains how the gravitational lensing phenomena of rings was predicted by general relativity, however I have yet to discover evidence that Einstein explained why there are 4 dots instead of a ring/crescent.