# Gravitational lensing in the form of optical equation $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{f}$?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, geometric-optics, lenses, gravitational-lensing

Gravitational lensing and light deviation is a well known subject in General Relativity.  I'm wondering if the null geodesics equation could be recast into the classical lenses equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{f}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
If it's possible, how should be defined the *gravitational focal length* $f$ ?

I never saw the geodesics equation written into the shape (1), even in the case of the Schwarzschild metric:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{d k^{\lambda}}{d \sigma} + \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda} \, k^{\mu} \, k^{\nu} = 0,
\end{equation}
where $k^{\mu} \propto \frac{d x^{\mu}}{d \sigma}$ is a null four-vector: $g_{\mu \nu} \, k^{\mu} k^{\nu} = 0$.

The *weak field approximation* is defined by the following metric:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
ds^2 \approx (1 + 2 \phi) \, dt^2 - (1 - 2 \phi)(\, dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2),
\end{equation}
where $\phi \ll 1$ is a gravitational potential (I'm using $c \equiv 1$ and metric-signature $(1, -1, -1, -1)$).

Could the geodesics equation (2) be reformulated into the shape of (1), assuming the special case of the Schwarzschild metric, or the weak field metric (3)?

**EDIT:**  I'm thinking about this kind of rays, with their focal length dependant on the impact parameter:
[image]

Comment: Duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92050/520

Comment: @dmckee, this question isn't exactly the same.  I'm asking about the geodesics equation reformulated as a lense equation.

Comment: The other questions answers this one; there is no focus so you can't have a equation describing the system that involves a focus.

Comment: @dmckee, I'm not sure this is true.  The focal length $f$ may depend on the ray (like the chromatic and spherical aberrations on real lenses), so $f \equiv f(q, p)$.

Comment: In those aberrations there is almost a focus. In gravitational lens there is nothing remotely like a focus.

Comment: @dmckee, well, I don't understand this.  A given light ray parallel to the optical axis (with some *impact parameter* $b$) will certainly converge to a point located on the optical axis, at a distance $f$ from the gravitational lense.

Comment: Cham,  I am not an expert in gravitational lensing,  but you can quickly see that there is a major difference with optics (convex lenses)  : the larger the impact parameter is,  the smaller the deviation is in grav.  lensing.   So no focus. Check also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing_formalism

Comment: @magma, thanks for the link.  Helpfull.

Comment: You are welcome